# Oracle SQL - Unable to get the data

Tags: sql, oracle

I could see data in the table with `last_update_date` as `02-AUG-16`

but when I query:

`select * from table_test where last_update_date = '02-AUG-16'`

No rows return.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: what is the datatype of that field?

Comment: Check date format for last_update_date column.

Comment: Does `where last_update_date >= date '2016-08-02' and last_update_date < date '2016-08-03'` return data? Sounds like you have times set in the column. If that finds data, query `to_char(last_update_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')` to see the times.

Comment: actually I tried last_update_date = to_date('02-AUG-16',DD-MON-YY)
Still that didn't work

Comment: SELECT * FROM table-test where last_update_date=  TO_CHAR(last_update_date, 'YYYY/MM/DD')

Comment: sorry its to_date('02-AUG-16','DD-MON-YY') return 02-AUG-16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dates in your table are not all at midnight, but your NLS_DATE_FORMAT setting isn't showing the time; and the implicit conversion you are doing is looking for exactly midnight.

If you do:

```
select to_char(last_update_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
from table_test
where last_update_date >= date '2016-08-02'
and last_update_date < date '2016-08-03'
```

you will see the time portion of each value. That `where` clause looks for any value which is on *or after* midnight on the date you specify, and before midnight the next day (though you're unlikely to have any after today). If you just did:

```
select to_char(last_update_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
from table_test
where last_update_date = date '2016-08-02'
```

or indeed, as you are implicitly doing:

```
where last_update_date = to_date('02-AUG-16', DD-MON-RR')
```

you won't see any matches, because none of the value found by the first query show the time as 00:00:00.

You should not rely on your session's NLS_DATE_FORMAT setting, either when querying or displaying data. It's better to always use [`to_char()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions200.htm#SQLRF06129) for display - at the last possible moment - and [`to_date()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions203.htm#SQLRF06132) for comparisons, specifying the [format model](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00212) you need, or [using ANSI date literals](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF51062) as I've done above. (You shouldn't reply on other NLS sessing either; in this case you are also assuming your NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE is English to match `AUG`).

Comment: Hey Alex .. Thanks for your detailed answer.. You are awesome :)

Answer (score 2):

To avoid any date format issues, try using to_date and specifying a format:

```
select * 
from table_test 
where last_update_date = to_date('2016-08-02','yyyy-mm-dd');
```

If that doesn't work, then to ignore any time issues (since by default, the above matches to 2016-08-02 @ 12:00:00 AM only), you can truncate the date in question:

```
select * 
from table_test 
where trunc(last_update_date) = to_date('2016-08-02','yyyy-mm-dd');
```

Comment: `trunc(last_update_date)` prevents any index on that column being used (unless you have a function-based index for the truncated value). It will work, but will be less efficient than it could be.

Comment: @learningKid - while the second query does work, please pay attention to Alex Poole's comment. Gordon showed a "longer" answer (more typing), but he explained the same thing as Alex did - you are better off not using "trunc()" (the easy way out) if you need efficient processing.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest writing this as:

```
select *
from table_test
where last_update_date >= date '2016-08-02' and
      last_update_date < date '2016-08-03';
```

This presumes that `last_update_date` is actually stored as a date.  Note that in Oracle, the `date` data type can also contain a time component, which might be invisible when you look at the value returned in a query.

The use of the `date` keyword allows you to input ISO standard date formats.

The use of `>=` and `<` allow Oracle to use an index on `last_update_date`, if one is available.

Comment: Thank you Gordon for your help :)